# how to calculate date difference in R when it involves BC and AD

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = data.frame(dt = c('0101-01-01','0023-10-20'), comment = c('BC','AD'))
```

the second dt is actually year -23 according to comment.

how can I make R recognise the first date is a BC and get the time difference from these two dates?

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: the year difference is around 123 years rather than 77 year (if directly subtract)

Comment: Try `v1 <- ymd(df$dt);v2 <- year(v1)
> i1 <- df$comment == "BC"; v2[i1] <- -1* v2[i1]
> diff(v2)`

Comment: confused by the (v1)>i1<- notation. would it be easier to write as ymd("0101-01-01") - something? thanks

Comment: Sorry, the `>` is from the console sign, it should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert to `numeric` after changing to `yearmon` class, change the sign to `-` for those having 'BC' in 'comment' and take the difference

```
library(zoo)
v2 <- as.numeric(as.yearmon(df$dt))
```

If we want to make the 'year' more approximate

```
v2 <- lubridate::year(df$dt) + 
                   (strptime(df$dt, format = "%Y-%m-%d")$yday + 1)/365

i1 <- df$comment == "BC"
v2[i1] <- -1* v2[i1]
diff(v2)
#[1] 124.75
```